Pool pump shorted circuit
I have a dedicated circuit where the to my pool pump runs underground.  It has shorted out somewhere but our electrician said that the breaker is still good and is sending current from our circuit box inside the house.  Can I cut this wire and test to see if the circuit coming from my house is still good. I don’t want to tear up my deck and open the wall to put in a new circuit unless that is absolutely necessary

"our electrician said that the breaker is still good and is sending current from our circuit box inside the house." If the breaker is still on, the problem with the pool circuit would not be a "short". A short is when the power and neutral wires improperly connect together and would trip the breaker, preventing it from staying on. Do you really mean that the pool pump is not powering up?

Do you know if the wires are in conduit or direct bury?  There should be a junction box near/on the pump to disconnect without cutting.

Pull a new cable through.

Did your electrician check the pump?
